# Pandas dataframe: unstack by order in subgroup, not by value

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, dataframe, stata

I'm trying to learn Python/Pandas and got what I believe is a pretty basic problem.

I have data of the following form:

```
id  X
1   1
1   2
2   2
2   3
3   4
3   5
3   5
3   3
3   3
3   4
4   3
4   4
4   6
```

I want to transform the data by something similar to an `unstack` format: I want to group by the `id`, sort the `X` values, put the first `X`-value in `x1`, the second `X`-value in `x2`, etc. The dataset is reasonably large (in excess of 1millon "lines"). Most of the values in `X` are unique (hence I don't want to use the **value** of X as the column name, but the **order** of X). After I'm done I'd want to end up with a dataframe looking like this:

```
id  x1  x2  x3
1   1   2   nan
2   2   3   nan
3   3   4   5
4   3   4   6
```

Comment: "about bloody time!" is a little ungracious, but I thought it would be going far too far to edit it out.

Comment: From the discussion below my answer, I now have to suggest that this is unclear.

Comment: point taken. I apologise for the "about bloody time!" and removed it from the question.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could do something like

```
>>> df = df.drop_duplicates()
>>> df = df.sort_values(["id", "X"])
>>> df["xcol"] = "x" + (df.groupby("id")["X"].rank().astype(int)).astype(str)
>>> df = df.pivot(index="id", columns="xcol", values="X")
>>> df
xcol  x1  x2  x3
id              
1      1   2 NaN
2      2   3 NaN
3      3   4   5
4      3   4   6
```

---

Step-by-step, first we can remove the duplicates and sort:

```
>>> df = df.drop_duplicates()
>>> df = df.sort_values(["id", "X"])
>>> df
    X  id
0   1   1
1   2   1
2   2   2
3   3   2
7   3   3
4   4   3
5   5   3
10  3   4
11  4   4
12  6   4
```

Then we can rank the elements in a groupby, and build the appropriate values we're going to use in the column (`cumcount` would have worked here as well):

```
>>> df["xcol"] = "x" + (df.groupby("id")["X"].rank().astype(int)).astype(str)
>>> df
    X  id xcol
0   1   1   x1
1   2   1   x2
2   2   2   x1
3   3   2   x2
7   3   3   x1
4   4   3   x2
5   5   3   x3
10  3   4   x1
11  4   4   x2
12  6   4   x3
```

and finally we pivot:

```
>>> df = df.pivot(index="id", columns="xcol", values="X")
>>> df
xcol  x1  x2  x3
id              
1      1   2 NaN
2      2   3 NaN
3      3   4   5
4      3   4   6
```

We could get exactly your described output format, if you insisted:

```
>>> df.columns.name = None
>>> df.reset_index()
   id  x1  x2  x3
0   1   1   2 NaN
1   2   2   3 NaN
2   3   3   4   5
3   4   3   4   6
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! A few things I wonder about: First, the astype(int) won't work since there are sometimes NANs in the data. I use a float instead, but then the new column namnes will be x1.0 x2.0 etc, not x1,x2. Is there a way to 'fix' this?  Second, the datatypes will not be preserved by the pivot. It's turned into text but  in reality is often datetimes, floats or ints. How could I 'fix' this? Thanks again!